# No cambia datos al hacer update con GridView y su función RowUpdating

Tags: asp.net, .net

Anteriormente hice una pregunta donde no podia generar un `update`, se solucionaron ciertos problemas pero no llegue a mi objetivo, en esta pregunta quiero saber cómo puedo hacer para que los `TextBox` reemplacen los valores que ya se traen desde la base de datos que tengo con Access.

Un ejemplo es que la base de datos trae `who = pedro`, `payroll = 123456`, y así sucesivamente pero al momento de "cambiar" los valores y dar clic en `update` estos se quedan igual.

Este es el codigo del `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 //Code display data
                conexiones.usuario_conexion connect = new conexiones.usuario_conexion();
                conexiones.usuario_conexion USBTable = new conexiones.usuario_conexion();
                DataTable dvt = USBTable.connect();
                if (dvt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dvt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

y este es el código del `GridView`:

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Code display data
    string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtid")).Text);
            string who = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtwho2")).Text;
            int payrol = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtpay2")).Text);
            string name = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtname2")).Text;
            string ou = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtou2")).Text;
            int pool = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtpool2")).Text);
            int team = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtteam2")).Text);
            int rol = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtrol2")).Text);

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET who = @who, payroll_number = @payrol, name = @name, ou = @ou, pool = @pool, team = @team, rol_id = @rol WHERE id = @id";

            command.Parameters.Add("@who", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = who;
            command.Parameters.Add("@payrol", OleDbType.Integer).Value = payrol;
            command.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ou", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ou;
            command.Parameters.Add("@pool", OleDbType.Integer).Value = pool;
            command.Parameters.Add("@team", OleDbType.Integer).Value = team;
            command.Parameters.Add("@rol", OleDbType.Integer).Value = rol;
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            connection.Close();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");

        }
    }
}
```

Y este es mi `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True"
    onrowcancelingedit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" onrowediting="GridView2_RowEditing" 
    onrowupdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="id" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Who">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtwho2" type="String" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("who") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtwho" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("who") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payroll Number">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpay2" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payroll_number") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtpay" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payroll_number") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtname2" type="String" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OU">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtou2" type="String" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ou") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtou" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ou") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pool">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpool2" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pool") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtpool" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pool") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtteam2" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("team") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtteam" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("team") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rol">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtrol2" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rol_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtrol" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rol_id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Cesar, los datos no se ven actualizados por cual de las siguientes razones: No se está actualizando la base datos y por tal razón no se ven los cambios o por que si se actualizando la base de datos correctamente pero los cambios no se ven reflejados en el grid?

Comment: No se ven actualizados por que no se estan actualizando en la base de datos , hace el commit y refresca la pagina pero no se cambian los datos, de igual manera hice un breakpoint y me percado de que cada txt tiene los datos anteriores, mas no los que ingrese

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que estés llamando a la instrucción `GridView1.DataBind();` antes de que se ejecute el evento `GridView2_RowUpdating`, lo que causaría que el `Grid` se vuelva a llenar con los datos iniciales.

Tomando en cuenta que este sea tu problema entonces revisa en los eventos `Page_Init` y `Page_Load` de tú página (en caso que los estés utilizando) que no estés actualizando el Grid en cada `Request`.

Para corregir esto debes realizar la siguiente condición para la correcta actualización del `Grid` dentro de estos eventos:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   GridView1.DataSource = tusdatos;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: En el `Page_Load` le agregue el `!PostBack` y al hacer clic sobre el boton de update del `GridView` este desaparece acabo de inserter el codigo que tengo en el `Page_Load`

Comment: Cuando escribes que "..este desaparece..", estas queriendo decir que el Grid no carga los datos nuevamente? Si esto es correcto entonces el código que tienes en el Page_Load pásalo para el evento Page_PreRender QUITANDO la condición `if(!IsPostBack)`. Evalua esto y me comentas nuevamente como te fue.

Comment: No, me refiero a que literalmente desaparece, hace como si la pagina se refrescara y desaparece el GridView

Comment: OK, intenta lo que te comente anteriormente

Comment: No se que fue lo que paso pero ahora me tira el siguiente error `Input string was not in a correct format.`  en la parte donde convierto el id

Comment: En el Debug, verifica que te esta retornando (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtid")).Text, Puede ser que este retornando vacío.

Comment: en efecto, me trae un valor 0 en el id... pero eso por que? antes de hacer los cambios que me referiste, si me traia el id 1 o 2, etc

Comment: Bueno, es un poco difícil hacer esto a distancia. Pero entonces vuelve al estado inicial donde el código estaba en el Page_Load con la condición del IsPostBack. Y ahora para asegurar que se actualice el Grid en el evento RowUpdating al finalizar este evento vuelve a obtener los datos de la base de datos y asígnalos nuevamente al Grid y no olvides ejecutar el método DataBind() otra vez.